# I don't understand arrays or indexes

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to write code that can calculate the area of multiple parcels of land. I don't understand how arrays and indexes are supposed to work, though.

This is the code, which doesn't work:

```
array = int(input('How many lands to process?'))
code = [0]*array
length = [0]*array
width = [0]*array
area = [0]*array2

for index in range(0,array):
    code[index] = str(input('Enter a parcel code for each land.'))
for index in range(0,array):
    length[index] = float(input('Enter the length in feet for each land.'))
for index in range(0,array):
    width[index] = float(input('Enter the width in feet for each land.'))    
    area=0
for index in range(0,array2):
    area[index]=float(length[index]*width[index])
for index in range(0,array2):    
    print(area[index])



for index in range(0,array):    
    print(code[index])
```

Comment: Before you can understand how it works, I think it is best if you understand [what it is](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/python-array/)... also, you may want to learn about [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Write your code to make one calculation, then allow  repeating that. I don't see any need to make lists or arrays (list like structure in numpy) here.

Comment: Where is `array2` defined?

Comment: I thought I had to split the array into separate ones.

I read the link, but I still don't understand an array. Is it just storing data in code, length, etc? What is the data that gets stored? How does an index retrieve the data? Can an array store multiple lines of data? How? Would there need to have special code to read multiple lines of data from an array, or is everything just packed into code, length, etc and then read automatically? How does the Python know how to handle the data?